# Need help in solving a linear algebra ( System of Equations) quiz problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am solving previous year quiz problem of my class and I am unable to solve this question in linear algebra.

> Let $A \in M_{m \times n}(\Bbb{R})$ and let $b_0 \in \Bbb{R}^m$. Suppose the system of equations $Ax = b_0$ has a unique solution. Which of the following statement(s) is/are true?
>
> 1. $Ax = b$ has a solution for every $b \in \Bbb{R}^m$.
> 2. If $Ax = b$ has a solution then it is unique.
> 3. $Ax = 0$ has a unique solution.
> 4. $A$ has rank $m$.

( Multiple answers can be correct)

Answer is :

> 2, 3

I know  the theorem that if $A$ is invertible then $Ax=0$ has only trivial solution and $A$ has rank $m$ and then $Ax=b$ has a solution for every $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$. But the problem is, how I can be sure if $A$ is invertible?

Kindly help.

Comment: In fact, you can't.

Comment: Please transcribe the problem in a block quote

Comment: @Michael Hoppe what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_0$ be the unique solution of the equation $Ax = b_0$.

1)) For instance, consider Michael Hoppe’s [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742744/need-help-in-solving-a-linear-algebra-system-of-equations-quiz-problem#comment7699004_3742771). Let $m=2$, $n=1$, $A=b_0=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$. It is easy to check that $x_0=1$. Since $A\Bbb R^n=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} \lambda \\ 0\end{pmatrix}:\lambda\in\Bbb R \right\}$, an equation $Ax=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$  has no solutions.

2))  Yes. Indeed, if $b\in\Bbb R^m$, $Ax=b$, and $Ax’=b$ then $A(x-x’+x_0)=Ax-Ax’+Ax_0=b-b+b_0$, so $x-x’+x_0=x_0$ and thus $x=x’$.

3)) We assume that $0$ from the question is a vector in $\Bbb R^m$. Then the answer is positive. Indeed, we have $A0=0$, and by (2), $0$ is a unique solution of the equation.

4))  The matrix $A$ from (1) has rank $1<2=m$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the system $Ax=b$ is solvable iff $b$ is an element of the span of the column vectors of $A$.  Now if this solution is unique the column vectors of $A$ are linearly independent.  Does this clear up things?

Comment: As columns are Linearly Independent, so why can't any vector b$\epsilon$$  R^{m} $ be written in terms of column vectors? That is why can't 1 be true? Also why can't A have rank m always? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Just a (nearly) trivial example. Let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$ Notice that not all $2$-dimensional vectors can be written in terms of the column vector(s) of $A$.  For that rank-question consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: why (2) and (3) must be true ie why if solution exits, then it must be unique? Sorry if I am asking too many questions but things are not clear to me.

Comment: what value of $b_0$ are you taking in your last comment to prove 4th option wrong?

Comment: can you please answer the questions that I have asked in comments?

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand your question concerning (4).  Obviously the rank of the matrix $A$ is $1$ ...